# Connect to MongoDB running on in a Docker Container

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm operating MongoDB within a Docker container and aim to connect it to another computer on the same network using the pymongo package.

For testing, I've bound the IP address to 0.0.0.0:

> net:
>
>         port: 27017
>
>         bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0

However, I'm unable to access the MongoDB and get the following error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: <my-Ip-Adeess>:27017: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 64f08a6061faf965ef, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('<my-Ip-Adeess>', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('<my-Ip-Adeess>:27017: timed out')>]>
```

Can you suggest any solutions?

Comment: Try `bindIpAll: true` which does the same.

Comment: What are you facing when you try to access the MongoDB? Please provide more details